# How to enable odbc connnections in new sql server setup?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-express

Fresh server 2012 R2 Essentials install, trying to get SQL Server Express to accept ODBC connections. My database is setup and I have all of my data populated, but now I am trying to get my reporting software to connect to the database and am not sure how to get the server to allow incoming connections.

Comment: The ODBC on the client side needs to be confirmed to be using the **`1.`** correct server name **`2.`** the correct TCP port number which the SQL connection is listening e.g. 1433 **`3.`** and that the username and password you are using to authenticate to the connection actually has access to the DB from the backend at the database level. Did you confirm that all three of these are correct and accurate? I assume you defined the ODBC with the standard ODBC management tool from the OS and then pointed the reporting software to use it -- the one that's already defined?

Comment: Also, what "reporting software" are you using exactly and what OS is that running on exactly?

Answer (score 2):

By default when Express Edition is installed the TCP/IP protocol is disabled. You need to go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable that protocol.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you Created a DSN to allow the connection?

If not:

1) Click start and search for "Data Sources (ODBC)" (this is also available in the "Administrative Tools" section of the Control Panel).

2) Go to the "System DSN" tab, and click "Add."

3) Follow the steps to add the Data Source

4) Use the Data source in the connection String of your reporting Service, and it should allow you to access the data.

**Note: you'll need to ensure you add a "Reporting Services" login user (with limited "READ" access) on the Server/Database you're reporting on.  Otherwise you won't be able to create a DSN.

Comment: Is this on the server or the client? My question is regarding the server setup to allow incoming odbc connections to the database. On the client side, I have tried to setup a DSN to the server and it appears that connections are not allowed.

Comment: You need to set the Reporting User up on the server, then add the DSN to the client using the Reporting User created.

Comment: I have a reporting user setup. I have tried to add the dsn and it will not connect... [Image of Services Running](http://i.imgur.com/UB1wuik.png) Do any of these services need to be running?